# How can you copy paste values in PyCharm dataframe view?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using pycharm dataframe view to inspect my dataframe. I wanted to copy paste the value in one cell. I select the cell, hit command+C, but it doesn't work. The 'copy' item in dropdown menu is grey and not selectable. How can I copy paste from dataframe view?

Pycharm version: 2017.3.3
MAC OS X

Comment: Why in the world is this not supported ..

Answer (score 12):

This isn't exactly what you wanted but if you right click in the debug variables menu on the variable that represents your dataframe click "Evaluate Expression" and insert the following and click evaluate:

```
df1.to_clipboard(sep=',')
```

Where df1 is replaced with the name of your dataframe. Then you can paste anywhere and pull out the values you need.

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html

Comment: You addressed this but just to underline: this does not help if you want the value of one cell.

Comment: yeah this is not a solution for a dataframe with 500k rows... :)

Answer (score 0):

During debug, using the variables you have access to at a breakpoint...

If its the **headers** you want,
right click the dataframe > Right click Columns > Compare values with clipboard.

If its **values** you want,
Expand the dataframe > Expand values> Expand array > Right click the 'row' you want to copy from > Compare values with clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct fix, but you can use the tabulate package.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys'))
```

From here, the output dataframe is viewable in console, and you can copy paste values there. Using this and dataframe view can be really useful for running additional queries/filters.